# Red Hat Openshift and Spring Cloud Configuration

Tags: containers, openshift

I am using Red Hat Openshift and Spring Cloud / Netflix OSS.  I have developed the applications and can get this working locally on my machine.  However, when I deploy to Openshift I cannot get the applications to register to the Eureka server.  I can get Eureka running but when I deploy the Eureka client applications they do not register to the Eureka server.

I have updated the properties to point to the Eureka server but the applications do not register.  I am running Eureka on port 8761.  The properties of my application (Zuul application) is as follows:

`spring.application.name=netflix-zuul-api-gateway-server`
   `server.port=8765`
   `eureka.instance.hostname=eureka-service.currency-conversion-service.svc` 
   `eureka.client.service-url.default-  zone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:8761/eureka/`
   `eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=false`

I have pointed the application to the service hostname that was allocated to the Eureka server in Openshift and I have added the port to the Eureka client URL as can be seen above.  I am not sure this is correct or I should be using the route.  I am new to Openshift and there does not seem to be much information on the net for Spirng Boot and Spring Cloud in Openshift.

Can anybody help please.

Thanks